# elements of symbolic matrix of size NxN

Tags: matrix, sympy

I'm trying to create a symbolic matrix (S) of general size (let's say LxL), and I want to set each element of the matrix as a function of the indices, i.e.:

```
S[m,n] = (u+i/2*(n-m))/(u-i/2*(n-m)) * (u+i/2*(n+m))/(u-i/2*(n+m))
```

I tried running this in sympy, and I got

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-a456d47e99e7> in <module>()
      2 S_l = MatrixSymbol('S_l',2*l+1,2*l+1)
      3 S_k = MatrixSymbol('S_k',2*k+1,2*k+1)
----> 4 S_l[m,n] = (u+i/2*(n-m))/(u-i/2*(n-m)) * (u+i/2*(n+m))/(u-i/2*(n+m))

TypeError: 'MatrixSymbol' object does not support item assignment
```

Searching through Stack Exchange I found this question from last year:
[Sympy - Dense Display of Matrices of Arbitrary Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885374/sympy-dense-display-of-matrices-of-arbitrary-size)
Which is unanswered and not exactly the same. Is it the same issue, or am I just trying to do an impossible thing in sympy (or computers in general)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is ancient, but I came across the same issue and figured I'd share a solution that works for me. **You'll need to use a [FunctionMatrix](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html#sympy.matrices.expressions.FunctionMatrix) object** instead of a MatrixSymbol. For background, I'm using SymPy 1.6.1 on Python 3.5.2.

Here's an example. Using the code below, I've setup some iteration symbols and the function `f(i,j)` I'd like to use for the elements of my matrix `u`.

```py
# Import SymPy for symbolic computations 
import sympy as sym

# Index variables
i,j = sym.symbols('i j', integer=True);
N = sym.Symbol('N', real=True, integer=True, zero=False, positive=True);

# The function we'll use for our matrix
def f(i,j):
    # Some arbitrary function...
    return i + j;

# Define a function matrix where elements of the matrix
# are a function of the indices
U = sym.FunctionMatrix(N, N, sym.Lambda((i,j), f(i,j)));
```

Now, let's try using the elements in the matrix by summing them all up...

```py
U_sum = sym.Sum(u[i,j], (i, 0, N), (j, 0, N));
U_sum
>>>
  N     N          
 ___   ___         
 ╲     ╲           
  ╲     ╲          
  ╱     ╱   (i + j)
 ╱     ╱           
 ‾‾‾   ‾‾‾         
j = 0 i = 0
```

Then, let's tell SymPy to calculate the summation

```py
our_sum.doit().simplify()
>>> N * ( N**2 + 2*N + 1 )
```

Answer (score -1):

This certainly can be done.  The [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#creating-matrices) offer some examples.  Here's one

```
>>> Matrix(3, 4, lambda i,j: 1 - (i+j) % 2)
Matrix([
[1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you can't define a matrix with a symbolic size using Matrix.